# c# Tridion 2011 How to get the filename from a Multimedia Component

Tags: 2011

I'm working with c# project and Tridion 2011 and I have a component item that is an image and I need to get the name of the upload image to this component. So I have this:

```
protected static Component GetComponentValue(string fieldName, ItemFields fields)
    {
        if (!fields.Contains(fieldName))
            return null;

        ComponentLinkField field = fields[fieldName] as ComponentLinkField;
        return field.Value;
    }
Component images = GetComponentValue(dataFieldName, fields);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're asking about the filename, then to get the original uploaded filename from a multimedia component you need to access it's `BinaryConent.Filename` property.

If you just mean the component's title, then it's just `.Title`

Comment: I mean the first one and what you gave me works perfect. Thanks!!